# Browser blocked a frame with origin <remote site> from accessing a frame in my site

Tags: authentication, cookies, iframe, same-origin-policy, samesite

My predecessor at my workplace built a website (mahlerclean.com) for a client that allows job applicants to log onto another site (joblinkapply.com) via an iframe. The client has recently gotten complaints from applicants who are not able to log into the site via the iframe.

I am able to reproduce the issue in Safari. When I go to https://www.mahlerclean.com/career-center/job-openings it does not let me log into https://www.joblinkapply.com/company/6435 from there, and I see this message in the Safari web console:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.joblinkapply.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.mahlerclean.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I have not been able to reproduce the issue in Firefox or Chrome though, and of course, if you navigate directly to https://www.joblinkapply.com/company/6435 (rather than through the iframe), it works fine in all browsers.

I control mahlerclean.com, but do not have any control over joblinkapply.com

My questions are:

1. Is there anything I can do to the site at mahlerclean.com that would
   allow the iframe to joblinkapply.com to work on all browsers?
2. Why am I only seeing the issue in Safari? Are the other browsers likely to get more strict (i.e. behave like Safari) in the future?
3. Is it even reasonable to try to support logins to a remote site through an iframe, or should I tell the client to ditch the iframe, and just link out to https://www.joblinkapply.com/company/6435?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame